# Getting options menu to do an action

Tags: java, android

I made a an options menu and am trying to get the buttons like save and open to be able to work and save the files to the internal storage on the device.  When i put in the code to do it it says that open and save cannot be applied.  Also its giving me an error saying that it needs an intent but im giving it a menuitem.  How would i go about making this an intent and fixing it? Here is my code.

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import static com.exaple.josh.unidrive.R.id.help;
import static com.exaple.josh.unidrive.R.id.list_item;
import static com.exaple.josh.unidrive.R.id.open;
import static com.exaple.josh.unidrive.R.id.save;
```

/**
 * Created by Josh on 1/31/2015.
 */

```
public class Documents extends ActionBarActivity {

@Nullable
@Override
public ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return super.getActionBar();
        }

EditText et;
EditText txtView;
private String data;
private String file = "mydata";

private Menu menuresource;


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuresource, (android.view.Menu) menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.documents);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(Menu item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItem(Menu.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE)) {
        case Save():
            showToast("Save Clicked");
            return true;
        case Open():
            showToast("Open Clicked");
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected((MenuItem) item);

    }
}


public void showToast(String message) {
    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: `item.getItem()` returns an `int` . And this `int` are the `id's` assigned to that menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `switch` statement is wrong inside `onOptionsItemSelected` and also, the signature of the method isn't correct.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) `onOptionsItemSelected` takes MenuItem as parameter

Something like this would do the job:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  //This method uses MenuItem as parameter
// Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save_item_id:
            showToast("Save Clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.open_item_id:
            showToast("Open Clicked");
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected((MenuItem) item);
   }
}
```

Where `save_item_id` and `open_item_id` are the ids you assigned to your menu items in your `menuresource.xml` file

Comment: When i tried putting in what you told me to it's giving me an error over 'item.getItemId()'